# Mirrored monitors of different resolution

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, resolution, mirroring

I want to purchase a 32" HD TV to use as a larger mirrored display for my PC. The problem is, my PC monitor is 16:10 and therefore has a resolution of 1920 x 1200, but the TV is standard 16:9, 1920 x 1080.

Will Windows allow them to be mirrored both at their native resolution? Or will I have to run them both at 1920 x 1080. They will be on seperate outputs, HDMI out for TV and DVI for monitor, if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Well I havnt actually purchased the TV yet, I just wanted to know if it would work first. Ill change the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The whole point of mirrored is to have the same resolution on both screens.

Personally, I would use both as independent/extended screens and just move to one when you need to use it.

Alternatively, look at both TV and monitor settings for overstretch / shrink settings and see which one looks better when not at native then put up with it on the other one.... If you can get the TV at native 1920x1080 then put that out to the pc monitor at 1920x1080 without it stretching, that will probably be the best and look the least distorted. (You may need to turn off auto calibration / any auto resolution settings)

Comment: If they were independent though, programs would likely pop up on the screen im not using, which will be annoying to say the least. The only way to fix this would be to disable the screen I am not using from Windows, but thats equally annoying.

If I just 1920 x 1080 to both monitors, I assume there will be black bars along the top and bottom of the desktop screen?

Comment: correct about black bars - but the only other real solution is to just use one a time and then unplug / unset the one you are not using. Other than this, if you set one screen as primary, you can be 99% sure that everything will pop up only on that one screen, unless it is something that was previously open and closed on the other.

Comment: Actually, I just remembered reading somewhere else that someone set up hotkeys to switch display profiles... Maybe if I set up two profiles, one for the TV and one for the desktop, then I can just switch between them with a hotkey. That would solve the problem with black bars. I assume would this work in my case too?

Comment: Yes. I personally do something similar. I have the different profiles set up within the Nvidia control panel and exported the settings a) for stretched to my monitor and b) stretched to my TV (My laptop can only stretch to one external at a time and I leave both DVI and HDMI plugged in). I actually use the Nvidia program to switch using the saved profiles, but I don't see why it wouldn't work with a hotkey

Comment: There are ways to do this on OSX and Linux operating systems so it's hard to believe there's not a way to do this on windows.

Comment: I've tried this solution with an NVidia GPU and it seems to be working.  I've even got the displays (one is a capture card not a display actually) running at different framerates https://superuser.com/questions/1371923/cloning-a-4k-panel-to-a-1080p-monitor

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

- While not a native solution, OBS has a Fullscreen Projector option if you right click on the Base Canvas that can stream one display to the other with very low latency.

---

**BACKGROUND**

- Problem: I like to mirror things from my computer monitor to my TV screen so my girlfriend can watch me play something while I use my monitor for its adaptive sync features.
- Problem: By downscaling my monitor to my TV screen using Window's or NVIDIA's built in "Mirror" feature, I wasn't able to use the GSYNC feature on my monitor which introduced screen tearing and gave me headaches. Not great.
- Problem: Answers online amount to "It just can't be done, your other display always has to be downgraded to your other display's settings." or "Oh, you can do that but you need to get _________ expensive multi-monitor software to do that" such as UltraMon.

Turns out there's a solution to this using OBS.

**SOLUTION**

1. In Windows Display Settings or your Graphics Card Control Panel, set your monitor to Extend mode, NOT Duplicate or Mirror mode.
2. Install OBS if you do not have it already.
3. Open OBS. If this is your first time using the software, it will probably prompt you for some settings related to streaming or recording. Either option is fine.
4. If you don't get prompted for anything, go to Settings->Video.
5. Set your Base (Canvas) Resolution to whatever the resolution of the secondary screen would be. The Base Canvas is the thing the preview screen that you see inside OBS.
6. In my testing, I don't think Output Resolution in Settings->Video will affect anything for the purpose we are using it for although I think it will affect recording/streaming.
7. Under Sources, you will need to set a source to capture. You could for example go to "Display Capture" or you could do "Window Capture" or "Game Capture". I won't go into much detail here since there's a lot of different sources you could potentially display and it's all documented on OBS documentation. The OBS documentation can be found here: https://obsproject.com/wiki/
8. Once you have that configured correctly, you should be able to see the Scene Item with a red border in or around the Base Canvas within OBS showing the window that is being captured. You may need to resize the capture window so that it fits correctly into the preview canvas. One easy way to do this is to right click on the Scene Item->Transform->Fit to screen.
9. If you right click on the Base Canvas, there will be an option that says "Fullscreen Projector (Preview)". It will then have another drop-down to select the monitor you would like to project to.
10. You should now see the screen cast to the other monitor.

In my testing, and on my (fairly powerful) desktop PC, the output has had low enough latency to not be detectable to the eye.