# Forcing a resolution higher than my monitor supports

Tags: resolution, intel-graphics

I have a 1366x768 max resolution monitor (win 10 laptop) . I want to be able to get a higher resolution ( or fool my computer into thinking that I have a higher res monitor ) . I did a fair bit of googling and found that one can do it in , AMD or Nvidia chips (something called DSR) but the issue is I have an intel internal gpu.

I checked out this software called [CRU](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU)
but basically I can only add custom resolutions that are smaller than the highest resolution that I can support (1366x728)

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRTU8_Ah9v4) talks about the exact same issue I have have
but it doesn't help much since it states that you can't do the procedure followed in the video for internal intel GPUs. So can I somehow do it on my internal intel gpu as well ?

EDIT : I have Intel HD 520 gpu and I've updated it to the latest version already. While I was able to set custom resolutions on the previous versions, I was still not able to set resolutions higher than 1366x768. That is why I have to use CRU to set custom resolutions now , but if I set anything more than 1366x768 , it just doesn't appear in the list of available resolutions I can select.

EDIT-2 : I found [this](https://linustechtips.com/topic/14001-how-to-run-higher-than-the-maximum-resolutions-on-your-display/) interesting article on the web that looks deeply on downsampling, however it still only mentions the external gpus like NVidea and AMD for the most part.

Comment: As a quick aside - DSR seems to also be known as integer scaling. There's driver support in intel's 11th gen for something similar it seems, but apparently OP's laptop's probably older.

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. Why do you want to fool your computer into thinking that you have a higher resolution monitor?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I want to be able to do that for the same reasons as in the video linked above ; I want my game to run in a higher resolution so I can have a more zoomed out view and hence , better gameplay.

Comment: You are not going to have a better game-play, because part of your screen will be outside of the monitor.

Comment: A higher resolution will not give you a zoomed out view. Assuming your sampling back down to your monitor resolution you’ll just get a worse performing game with slightly better anti-aliasing. Most likely you want to adjust the FOV in the game, research how to increase that in your specific game. Note, this too will decrease performance.

Comment: @Jarrod Christman Just have a look at the video linked above. It literally creates a higher resolution for a zoomed out display in-game. All I wanna ask : Is there a way downsampling can be achieved in internal gpus like my intel hd 520

Comment: Let’s go with what game? That game in the video looks to allow more zooming out when the resolution is higher, but that is a game specific behavior. I use DSR, it just renders the game at a higher resolution and samples it back down to your output resolution... this, with the majority of games will not zoom anything out. Most of the time a zoom out is done by increasing the FOV. If your use case is the exact game in the video, does your monitor support higher resolutions than native? For example, some 1080p monitors accept a 4K signal but then sample it back down.

Comment: Depending on the game, some also have different settings for internal rendering versus output rendering. In the newer COD MW I render at 4K 120Hz and output to 1440p 120Hz.

Comment: @JarrodChristman Yes , that game is the exact same game I'm trying to play , and no the highest resolution my monitor can support is 1366x768. I just updated my system bios , and still no luck .

Comment: I am sorry, what are you trying to do? I think if you forced a resolution higher than the resolution the screen supports, then the screen would only display part of the graphics, and the pixels outside of the pixel range the screen supports, will be outside of the screen...

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς Precisely this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRTU8_Ah9v4. My game (the same game in the video) allows zooming out if it is forced to play at a higher resolution.

Comment: If that is what you wanted(to force a game run at higher resolutions), I can give you a few advices, find the configuration files of the game, they are usually .ini files, maybe .cfg files, try to find the files in the game folder, if no luck, try to find the files in Documents and in AppData, there usually is a folder with the name of the game, if you found the file, open it in Notepad++ (not notepad), and change the resolution in the file, see if it helps...

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς Gotcha. Let me give it a try and I'll update my findings.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς  [I modified the values in the registry editor instead] [1] .Changed the screen height, screen width and screen size values to show a 1920x1080 res , but nothing changed in the game.( I noticed after a reboot , the screen height and screen width stayed as the new updated values , but the screen size rolled back to the default 1366 ). Any clues what else I could try ?                                                 [1]: https://imgur.com/a/4VNvC8l

Comment: Did you change screen size? If not, change it to match screen width; If it does not help, try to modify permissions of that key and prevent it from being changed, see if that helps...

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς yup , tried it and even though the registery values don't change anymore ,  the in game resolution doesn't change from 1366x768 either. :/

Comment: (1) Do you still have installed the old Intel® Graphics Control Panel? If yes, it might be able to define a custom resolution. (2) There's also the old [PowerStrip](https://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm). (3) And also [ControlMyMonitor](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/control_my_monitor.html). Useful reference:[Understanding EDID](https://www.extron.com/article/uedid).

Comment: would setting a custom/higher resolution actually be visible on the monitor? I thought you would get out of range errors if you did it.

Comment: @harrymc yes to the first question, and I have used powerstrip and and controlmymonitor but they don't let me create custom resolutions above 1366x768 either.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek having researched online for quite a bit, I have observed that users who had 1366x768 were able to upscale to resolutions like 1920x1080 and above using DRS (downscaling) on Nvidea and AMD GPUs. Only when they tried to upscale it to absurd resolutions like 4k and 5k did they get the out of range errors.

Comment: CRU let me define a higher resolution than the maximum, but in order for CRU to agree to it, I had to lower the refresh rate from 60 to 30.

Comment: @harymc Inside the CRU utlility , I can pretty much define any higher resolution , but in the Dispal resolution section that's in the Display Settings, I can only see the custom resolutions that are lower than 1366x768. So even if I have created 2 resolutions (1252x700 - some bogus resolution-just to check if it shows in the display settings or not , and 1920x1080) only the 1252x700 resolution appears and is available to select in the list of other resolutions in the display settings.

Comment: CRU works for me on an NVIDIA gpu, although a reboot is required for the custom resolution to be available under Display Settings.

Comment: From my admittedly cursory research - nvidia, amd and gen11 and newer intel processors support this in driver - so it should work. on that. OP's got an older intel GPU.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: [Intel HD Graphics 520](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-520.149940.0.html) is of Skylake technology, which the latest version of [CRU](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) claims to support.

Comment: I'm talking about os level supersampling

Comment: @Tanuj: Do resolution by CRU appear after a reboot?

Answer (score 4):

There are probably more elegant ways to do this - and I've not tested this on the specific game but a really hacky way to get a higher resolution is to simply mirror the output of a higher resolution 'screen' onto a lower resolution screen. You should be able to test this with a loaner monitor (which I recommend), but for production use, you want a dummy HDMI adaptor - these are often used by bitcoin mining folks, and in certain situations where software won't run without a monitor in place.

In theory, these will go up to 4698x2160, but I am doubtful you will get a usable gaming experience shoehorning such a high resolution into a cheap and cheerful essentially 720p screen. There's a [really nice technical writeup](https://goughlui.com/2019/06/02/review-teardown-generic-hdmi-cheater-dummy-plug-4k-uhd/) of it here, and its a fairly standard part you can get for under a fiver

This will give you a 'display output', with no real display. The next part of out trick will be to expose this to our meaty human eyes. On my desktop, on which I am testing this

[image]

Display 3 is my emulated display. Display 4 is a lower resolution (1280x800) screen where I want to run this. While you can typically, natively only mirror at the lowest resolution of all your monitors, [there's a great solution on superuser already](https://superuser.com/questions/70927/mirrored-monitors-of-different-resolution) we can tailor to our needs.

Your mileage may vary, and you may choose to tweak the settings

You can always go through the wizard again if you need to

[image]

I'm not streaming, and I don't need to worry about latency over the internet

You want to run OBS on the target, physical monitor. On my setup its display 4

My base/canvas resolution is what's displayed. I want the full 1080p screen captured (and it seems to go up to 1440p at best)

[image]

Picking the 'fake' monitor is an easy way to go or just set it to 1080p

You can then set things up on the main OBS UI

[image]
You need to add a source here -

[image]

display capture works for me

[image]

Add a new source (it ignores display 4)

[image]

[image]

this will show your virtual display on the main UI

[image]

Rightclick and select fullscreen projector preview.

Now you need to move your mouse from the physical screen to the virtual one. Right clicking on the physical screen will give you the OBS rightclick menu.

You might need to tweak it further for aspect ratios and letterboxing, but for most part it seems to work with the smaller copy of calc running on the emulated screen.

Since your screen is a window, while I don't have a copy of the software you want to run, I can demonstrate the scaling effect

[image]
You will need some tweaking to get it perfect, but this should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Very informative, doesn't fit my budget and time constraints. Thanks anyway for the insight. Will definitely try that sometime. +1

Comment: If there was a way to replace the HDMI dongle in software, this might work better. I happened to have these lying around. The problem with doing it on modern systems is you need a signed driver for many things, and I can't think of one that would do this on windows 10 and newer.